# VueJS Reducing JSON return data by category and sum associated values

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

I have raw data coming from a mongodb/nestjs API via axios with the format of:

```
created_at: "date"
quantity: "number"
month: "string"
organization: "string"
state: "string"
category: "string"
year: "date"
_id: "numeber"
```

By using axios and getting the data I can generate a manageable output:

```
        .get(`${server.baseURL}/quantity/quantities`)
        .then(response => {
            this.rawData = response.data
            console.log(this.rawData);
            this.rawDataB = this.rawData.map(( {category, quantities} ) => ({category, quantities}))
            console.log(this.rawDataB)
        })
```

This console log of rawDataB produces the following output array:

```
[
{category: "string",
quantities: "number}
]
```

Because I have monthly data for each category, I have an array of about 100 objects with this format, one for each month.
So I have...:

```
[{category: "string", quantities: "number"}]
```

for each month starting from January to September. So each category has about 8-9 objects associated with the same category, different months, and different quantities.

I want to reduce this to the following format, but can't seem to figure it out:

```
[
{ category: "string", quantities: "number }
]
```

for each category -- essentially removing the category name duplicates by way of this external function:

```
export function removeDuplicate (a, b) {
  if (a.indexOf(b) < 0) {
    a.push(b)
  }
  return a
}
```

But when do this, the date keys get lost and only provides me with arrays within array:

```
[
[ "category", number],["category", number]...
]
```

for each category. Notice, the number was changed to an integer and not a string anymore

Any thoughts on how I might be able to achieve the data format of?

```
[
{category: "string", totalQuantity: number}
]
```

Comment: the data format descriptions are very confusing, maybe clarify a bit? also I don't understand what you mean when you say "the date keys get lost."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a library... take note of [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
const rawData = [
    { category: "january", quantities: "2" },
    { category: "february", quantities: "2" },
    { category: "january", quantities: "2" },
    { category: "february", quantities: "2" },
    { category: "january", quantities: "2" },
    { category: "february", quantities: "2" },
    { category: "january", quantities: "2" },
    { category: "february", quantities: "2" }
];

const formattedData = rawData.reduce((previousValue, { category, quantities }) => {
    if (!previousValue[category]) {
        previousValue[category] = { category, totalQuantity: 0 };
    }
    previousValue[category].totalQuantity += +quantities;
    return previousValue;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(formattedData));
```